# How to text in selected polygons using QGIS in geojson file?

Tags: qgis, geojson

[image][image]

I have upload geojson file in QGIS. there total 8 polygons (8 taluka's co-ordinates) now, my question is I want to just highlight 4 polygons( 4 taluka's) and display in selected 4 polygons ( "number of villages " &" area for crop" ) for selected 4 crops . and display names in the each polygons also. is it possible ?

[image]

I want to display  in "Kannad" :  "Number of villages :  12, "Area for Crop" : 20 Hectare "  only

Comment: To label the polygons, you can use the labeling tool (menu Layer -> Labeling), check 'Label this layer with' and select the column which contains the info you want to label with. But you didn't mention if the number of villages and the area for crop info exists in the attribute table.

Comment: @geoSAM, I suggest you post your comment as an answer. That way Kiran can accept it.

Comment: @Fezter, Agree , :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To label your map in QGIS:

1. Use the Labeling tool (menu Layer -> Labeling or Layer Properties-> Style)
2. Select "Labels" tab and choose the option "show label for this layer".
3. Under "Label with", select the field name you wish to use for the label. You can also use the expression (ε) button, to create labels from different fields by writing something like `'number of villages ' + "FIELD1" +' area' + "FIELD2"`,  where FIELD1, FIELD2 the fields where the number of villages and area info lies in.

Comment: ,Thanks and Can you help me how to text type (title) in the co-ordinates map ? Like I want to type "COTTON " as a title

Comment: can you tell me how can I type "tittle" as cotton " crop ? , I have attached a photo in my question